# CNAME for subdomain to different host?

Tags: dns, subdomain, cname

A friend asked me to help them with a new website on a subdomain that has a different host than the main domain.

The domain is registered with Host A, the name servers point to Host A, however the CNAME for the main domain points to Host B. A subdomain has been created and "points to" its subdirectory (i.e. folder123). However, the host does not have a typical cpanel, it's oversimplified and I can't see that that "points to" record is. Either way, the subdomain is not bringing up the new website in the folder.

So do I need to create a CNAME record for the subdomain that point to the folder on Host A? Or would I get Host A's IP and create a A record to that?

Answer (score 1):

For DNS of domain.com add:
`sub.domain.com. 14400 IN A IP_OF_NEW_SERVER`

Comment: Thanks for throwing in! I am not sure why this question did not get any attention. The system flagged this as a low quality post because of it's size. In your answer, you have not addressed the *CNAME record for the subdomain that point to the folder on Host A* part of the question. Basically, the answer is that a CNAME cannot point to a folder and that the web server configuration would have to be modified. But how?? IIS or Apache? I always assume Apache since that is common and what I know. Cheers!!

Comment: Good point. From my perspective - folder was unclear - so I've decided to say what I know... That means if you need subdomain on separate host - put that entry to DNS - and perhaps that explanation was missing.